# Conditional typing of input props

Tags: typescript

I need to make parameters that depend on the transmitted field type.
I don’t understand why the handler has a any type of arguments

```
type TInputType =  'text' | 'number' | 'date';

type THandler<V> = (e: Event, data: { value: V }) => void


type TProps<T extends TInputType = TInputType> = {
  type: T
} & (
  T extends 'number' ? {
    value: number
    handler: THandler<number>
  } : {
    value: number
    handler: THandler<string>
  }
)


function input(props: TProps) {
  console.log(props);
}

const val = 1234;

input({ type: 'number', value: val, handler: (e, { value }) => {
----------------------------------------------^----^--------------
Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
Binding element 'value' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7031)
------------------------------------------------------------------
  console.log(e, value)
} });
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a generic type parameter to the `input` function so that TypeScript can use it to infer the type information from the argument — currently, `TInputType` is always used because it is the default:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgkgOzAV2Dc0C8UBEwIAewOUAPrgsgLYBGEATieTgCYCG+OA3AFA+iRYACTYIWAGwYAeAGoA+KNgAUEAFxQAogDcICYABoo7YG3UBvKFrbjkaqDKgBfAJSKFWgPYBLFr34ZYAAV6DzAAZykYKEJ8MTDYRBQ0AOx4JFR0SAVMHigoADIoCwE7KMdcgqglCryomN0WeJxKWgYSAH4imryeqxs7Frp6Xh7RqAALUQkGdRgRMUl6KUGGORGx8rGoc27Rvtt1FeHdnsmFmeEpxakw4HovBABzNZPNqGc-ADNkBABjYC8HgQUAeSUi0SIDXiaSSmQgciUYBC4VmwVCERgclcZgqAHpcVtRgA9EmksnkilEwmE0kVX5AsIeSQAOnEHkeiORYQ+PHKPHpCFulmsiigAEYAEwAZgALH5QaglDi8iV1M1qEMcPoKvs7H1tXkztN6OoVIYLLqnK5MApldStviie1ugLGSy2RyIIZdTy8o5tS5eEA)

```ts
function input<T extends TInputType>(props: TProps<T>) {
  //          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^
  console.log(props);
}

const val = 1234;

input({
  type: "number",
  value: val,
  handler: (e, { value }) => {
               //^? (parameter) value: number
    console.log(e, value);
  },
});
```